# Is it possible to distribute an app extension binary for inclusion in another project?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension

Let's say you have a consulting agency that is developing a 3rd party keyboard for a client.

You want that client to be able to include the keyboard, which is an app extension, in their code, but for whatever reason, you'd prefer if they didn't see the source. So you compile your app extension to a binary (OK, maybe two -- one for the simulator and one for 64-bit ARM).

Is it possible for the client to then include this binary as another target in their project?